# Set Facebook URL to Share with Parameters

Tags: html, facebook

Is it possible to crate SHARE link for specific page in my website? For instance:

```
http://www.MY-SITE.COM/index.php?page=show_book&book_id=$book_id
```

I tried:

```
<a title='Share on Facebook'
  href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.MY-SITE.COM/index.php?page=show_book&book_id=$book_id'  
  target='_blank'>
     Share on Facebook
 </a>
```

but it doesn't get the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If the parameters are getting stripped, try url encoding them (rawurlencode() in PHP).

Also make sure your target share page is serving up different open graph meta tags based on the parameters.

Comment: you need to make sure to URL Encode the question mark (i.e. the entire URL string) and not just the parameters. It's probably the double question marks (the first to start the query string and the second in your URL) that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Share button is old. FB recommends to use the like-Button

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to `echo` your `$book_id`:

```
<a title='Share on Facebook'
  href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.MY-SITE.COM/index.php?page=show_book&book_id=<?php echo $book_id ?>'  
  target='_blank'>
     Share on Facebook
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to this, which will work amongst other providers too (twitter, g+ etc) is to use a url shortening service like http://bit.ly.

Answer (score 0):

replace `&` with `%26` something like

```
$url = 'http://www.MY-SITE.COM/index.php?page=show_book%26book_id='.$book_id;
<a title="Share on Facebook"
  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?=$url?>">Share on Facebook</a>
```